# extjs tooltip not showing

Tags: extjs

I have a toolbar like this:

```
tbar : {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    tooltip: 'Right click to clear',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'form',
        padding: 2,
        height:25
    }]
}
```

My tooltip does not show up. I have done QuickTips.init(). Also, is it possible to include some dynamic text in the tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are attempting to put a toolbar inside of a toolbar.  Are you sure that is really what you are trying to do?

Your tooltip probably does not work because tooltip is not a valid property of the toolbar object.

As for dynamically altering the tooltip text, you have the getText(string) method.

According to the ExtJS API documentation, Toolbar does not have a tooltip property. In order to use the tooltip, you'll need to apply the tooltip directly to an HTML element, or use the tooltip on a valid, supported object.